# Committing code from paperspace gradient to gitlab

Tags: github, gitlab

I have trained a model on Gradient Paperspace and I am trying to commit to a repo on gitlab.

Here is my code and output. What step am I doing wrong?

```
root@n9763ntd0q:/notebooks# git init 
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /notebooks/.git/
root@n9763ntd0q:/notebooks# git add .
root@n9763ntd0q:/notebooks# git commit -m "first commit"
[main 9e175a4] first commit
 1 file changed, 5 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)
root@n9763ntd0q:/notebooks# git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/rezaafra/sentiment-progression.git
fatal: remote origin already
root@n9763ntd0q:/notebooks# git push -u origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/gradient-ai/TensorFlow.git'
root@n9763ntd0q:/notebooks#
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that the origin is already set to 'https://github.com/gradient-ai/TensorFlow.git'.

You can check what the origin is set to with:

```
git remote -v
```

So instead of adding an origin, you need to change it:

```
git remote set-url origin https://gitlab.com/rezaafra/sentiment-progression.git
```

I'm a noob working my way through these issues on Paperspace Gradient and am posting in case others might benefit.